# Making custom encryption with javascript (stuck in decrypt function)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make new custom encryption engine with javascript, but i have a problem when i make a decryption function. In my decryption function I don't understand how to switch 3 characters to 1 character. In the decryption function section, 3 characters from the case I do not want are changing to the characters that are returned.

If you need my full code, i can share in here.

So please help me to solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English :)

```html
<body>
 <h3>Encrypt and Decrypt</h3>
 <!-- Encrypt -->
<!--  <input placeholder="Ketikan sesuatu disini, pasti bisa:v" id="input"><br>
 <button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button> -->
 <!-- Decrypt -->
 <br><input placeholder="Ketikan sesuatu disini, pasti bisa:v" id="input2"><br>
 <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button>
 <!-- Result -->
 <div id="result"></div>
 <!-- Enginenya -->
 <script>
  function encrypt(){
   var rawtext = document.getElementById("input").value;
   var temptext = "";
   for(i = 0; i < rawtext.length; i++){
    temptext += enc(rawtext[i]);
   }
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = temptext;
  }
  function decrypt(){
   var rawtext = document.getElementById("input2").value;
   var temptext = "";
   for(i = 0; i < rawtext.length; i++){
    temptext += dec(rawtext[i]);
   }
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = temptext;
  }
  function enc(x){
   switch(x){
    case " " :
    return " ";
    break;

    case "A" :
    return "+/=";
    break;

    case "B" :
    return "36=";
    break;
   }
  }
  function dec(x){
   switch(x){
    case "+/=" :
    return "A";
    break;

    case "36=" :
    return "B";
    break;
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Obligatory warning that rolling your own crypto is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through singular chars & passing them to `dec()`, eg. If you enter "+/=", you are actually calling `dec('+')` then `dec('/')` then `dec('=')`

When decrypting the entered value, you'll have to split them into groups of 3 & then pass those.

```
function decrypt(){
    var rawtext = document.getElementById("input2").value;
    var temptext = "";

    for(i = 0, charsLength = rawtext.length; i < charsLength; i += 3){
        temptext += dec(rawtext.substring(i, i + 3));
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = temptext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take three caracters for decrypting an encrypted string.

```
while (i < rawtext.length) {
    temptext += dec(rawtext.slice(i, i += 3)); // take from index i and increment i by 3
}
```

```js
function encrypt() {
    var rawtext = document.getElementById("input").value,
        temptext = "",
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < rawtext.length; i++) {
        temptext += enc(rawtext[i]);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = temptext;
}

function decrypt() {
    var rawtext = document.getElementById("input2").value,
        temptext = "",
        i = 0;
    while (i < rawtext.length) {
        temptext += dec(rawtext.slice(i, i += 3));
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = temptext;
}

function enc(x) {
    switch (x) {
        case " ":
            return " ";
        case "A":
            return "+/=";
        case "B":
            return "36=";
    }
}

function dec(x) {
    switch (x) {
        case "+/=":
            return "A";
        case "36=":
            return "B";
    }
}
```

```html
<h3>Encrypt and Decrypt</h3>
<input placeholder="Ketikan sesuatu disini, pasti bisa:v" id="input"><br>
<button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
<!-- Decrypt -->
<br><input placeholder="Ketikan sesuatu disini, pasti bisa:v" id="input2"><br>
<button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button>
<!-- Result -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're iterating over the text to decrypt character by character, but then your `dec` function expects three characters. This never happens, so `dec()` returns undefined.

Example:

```
decrypt("36=") -> 
    dec("3") + dec("6") + dec("=") ->
    undefined + undefined + undefined
    undefinedundefinedundefined
```

You should change your decrypt function to avoid this. Additionally, some pointers:

- You don't initialise `i` in your encrypt/decrypt function
- There's no need for a `break;` after a `return` in your case statements as return will end the execution.

Edit: Here's an example with map since some other answers had some with for loops. And also because I suspected it could be done with one line (and I was right!)

```html
<body>
 <h3>Encrypt and Decrypt</h3>
 <br><input placeholder="Ketikan sesuatu disini, pasti bisa:v" id="input2"><br>
 <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button>
 <div id="result"></div>
 <script>
  function decrypt(){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input2").value.match(/.{1,3}/g).map(dec).join('');
  }
  function dec(x){
   switch(x){
    case "+/=" :
      return "A";
    case "36=" :
      return "B";
                default:
                  return "?";
   }
  }
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, for helping :)